# Selected item color in Spinner

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

How to define Spinner style to achieve selection result like in the [Material Guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-dropdown-buttons)?

I'm using `Widget.AppCompat.Spinner` but selected item text have the same color like other items not accent.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose this is the `Spinner` you're using,

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
      android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
      android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
      android:popupBackground="@color/spinner_popup"/>
```

make ur `spinner_bg.xml` look like this...

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/whatever" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/whatever" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/whatever" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/whatever" android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/selected_spinner_item"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/normalwhatever"/>
```

Comment: I'm asking about selected item text color. Not background.

Comment: Did u try this? Fifth line in the spinner_bg.xml is for the `textColor` of activated item. Please try and update. `<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/selected _spinner_item"/>`

Comment: Yes! And this is not working. More, this is crashing because of color tag used instead of drawable.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Editing it.

Comment: Yes, after that is not crashing but selected item text color stay the same.